# Python 3: Can you pass a method from one class to a method in another class when the object to invoke on does not exist yet

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, parameters

```
class A:

    def Amethod(self, method):

        b = B()
        b.method()

class B:

    def Bmethod(self):

        print('Hello')
```

I want to be able to call the Amethod method with Bmethod as input:
#general idea, but code is of course invalid

a = A()

a.Amethod(Bmethod)

now an issue here is that Bmethod is not recognised as it needs to be invoked on an instance of the B class. However, I can't do this because the B object that I want to invoke Bmethod on does not yet exist.

Comment: Pass the *name* of the method as string and `getattr(b, method)()`…?!

Comment: If you pass `BMethod`, you can simply call `method(b)` (though this doesn't play well with inheritance and is not typically something you want to do).

Comment: Thanks for this chepner, I went with what deceze recommended and it worked out great (for now)